# iCloud, created @me.com email with wrong Apple ID, how to claim it with correct Apple ID?

Tags: mail.app, icloud

I logged into iCloud with an old Apple ID (abc@mac.com) because I was hoping I could use that old email address with iCloud.  However, it told me I had to create a new @me.com email address in the iCloud setup tool so I did (abc@me.com).

The thing is, my preferred Apple ID is actually different (abc@gmail.com), that's the Apple ID I've been buying iTunes music with for years, so I want to keep using it for iCloud too.

So I logged out of iCloud, and logged in with the "correct" Apple ID abc@gmail.com

Then I went to configure Mail for iCloud to use my newly created abc@me.com, but it's prompting me to create a "new" @me.com email.  It won't let me use the abc@me.com that I just created under the abc@mac.om Apple ID. :(

Since I already have and like abc@me.com, I want to use that one, but it won't let me.  It insists on creating a new @me.com

Is there any way to associate the newly created abc@me.com email address with a different Apple ID than the one I created it with?  Or am I stuck creating yet another @me.com email address?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There appears to be no way to do what I need.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you would like to change the primary email address associated with your apple id, this is not only possible but fairly easy to do if you have the right site.

Click "Manage your account" about halfway down http://appleid.apple.com and you should be presented with an option to edit "Apple ID and Primary Email Address".

Answer (score -2):

I changed the email of my iTunes account and then logged into iCloud with a different Apple ID with the email address I wanted to use.